# Serverless framework with DynamoDB: Lambda function work, but data hasn't been saved to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have dealing with some trouble serverless framework and DynamoDB.

After my lambda function executed,
the `context.succeed(result)` would return the result,
but nothing write into the DynamoDB.

Here is the link of [demo repo](https://github.com/abalone0204/serverless-demo).

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252815/how-to-access-dynamodb-from-aws-lambda-when-using-serverless-framework)

And I added the resource to the `s-resources-cf.json`, 
then `serverless resources deploy` again.
After sending the request, it still do nothing with DynamoDB.

Here's the thing I've done:

- Create a table: `posts` with primary key in specific region
- Attach `AdministratorAccess` to my `IAM` role(I know it's bad to do that.)
- Add  `{"Effect": "Allow", "Action": ["*"], "Resource":"arn:aws:dynamodb:${region}:*:table/*"}` to the `s-resources-cf.json`

Do there anything I still misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your demo repo does not appear to be including the AWS SDK & setting the region as noted in the [Getting Started guide](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk).  I.e.:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var DOC = require("dynamodb-doc");

AWS.config.update({region: "us-west-1"});
var docClient = new DOC.DynamoDB();

...
```

Note that `dynamo-doc` was deprecated almost a year ago.  You may want to try the [DynamoDB DocumentClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) instead.  This updated API has much more clear error-handling semantics that will probably help point out where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks! But I realize that there has some problem in my `handler.js`

Comment: @Denny what are the problems you have with DynamoDB DocumentClient?